# Delayed rollback (ado.net) not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, rollback

I wish to do some sort of delayed rollback (not in batch) in sample c# desktop app 
1 button inserts the data, the other rolls it back

I tried the following but it is not working

```
error:  The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.
```

.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        //conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        try
        {
            //tran = conn.BeginTransaction("Transaction1");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("begin transaction", conn);
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert into employee values ('6','aaaaaa','111')", conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

        }
        catch { }
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("rollback transaction", conn);
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Is what i am attempting even possible? or am I just going at it the wrong way?

Comment: Did you figure anything out?

Comment: As long as the connection is shared between the two buttons it works.
As soon as you close and reopen, both ways don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Youch.

TECHNICALLY, everything you have in button2_Click is "new", so there is no "tie back" to the original "begin transaction" statement.

But I really don't think you want to do the manual "begin transaction" and "rollback transaction" statements.

I ~~think~~ you want to try and make this variable:

```
**tran** = conn.BeginTransaction("Transaction1");
```

this "tran" variable a member variable whose scope is bigger than one command button.
(Lets say you make it a member variable and rename it to _transaction)

and then either call

```
_transaction.Rollback();
```

or

```
_transaction.Commit()
```

But wow.  That's is flakey.  I'm just giving you an idea if you're really bent on doing it.

Comment: :) Actually I've started there..but wanted to do it my way because it seemed more manual 
I thought it would work because I am sending these statements to the db engine. 
and in Sql Server these commands don't have to be executed in the same batch

Comment: I have no idea if "your way" will actually work.  But to even attempt it, you have to allow the scope of (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("begin transaction", conn);) to be bigger than just the command button.  It needs to be a member variable at the least.  You're getting the error because the first cmd falls out of scope after the button1_click, so button_2 "rollback tran" has no idea what you're talking about, thus your error.

Comment: will try that and get back to you